# Unload Realm because of new database file

Tags: ios, realm

I am trying to update precompiled database in my app using a new database file downloaded from the internet. However when I download the file and replace the old one used by Realm with it, Realm still uses the old one till the next app restart. Unfortunately I still need to open the first DB to copy some data from it before downloading a new database. Is there a possiblity to force unload/reload the whole database?

Comment: It's very unclear (to me) what you're attempting to achieve here. Are you trying to overwrite a Realm database file on-disk from one you've downloaded? Some code snippets would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake and I accidentally created a new instance of Realm. The problem is that Realm instances are cached. I needed to use `autoreleasepool {}` and ensure that Realm is created only in the block.